# In Magento 2 what crons set maintenance as enabled?

Tags: php, magento, cron, magento2

I would like to know what crons on Magento 2 enables the maintenance mode?. I've been experiencing several issues because my site suddenly enables maintenance mode at some hours during the day. Could you give me a glimpse on this please?.

Comment: I dont know but i guess you are faster by looking at all the crons that are running, get their names and search for "{name} maintenance".

Comment: Well... actually there's no clue about a cron that runs and its name is maintenance...

Comment: We use nginx, varnish, separated server for DB, and so on.. is there something there that enables maintenance automatically ?. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maintenance mode is not handled by cron.

Crons are more to support Magento execute things that are to be done at a regular frequency.
Its also used to process post activities of customer: orders or other activities. So that there is no delay in customer experience.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2, maintenance mode is enabled to set your application while you are maintaining, upgrading, or reconfiguring your site.

The command used: bin/magento maintenance:enable

If your Cron enables the maintenance mode, you need to check and debug the Cron code and file that enable the maintenance mode.

Cron is more about executing particular tasks or activities such as newsletters, orders, customers, sitemaps, reindexing, and emails in Magento 2.

For full details please check: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/setup-magento-cron-job/